# d3 arrows in Force Directed Graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I am puzzled. Why by simply copying and pasting the example http://bl.ocks.org/1153292 the arrows do not align. (see below)

[image]

UPDATE: it works in chrome and safai but not in Firefox... even more puzzled. Any ideas?

What would you change in the example to get straight lines instead of curves?

Thanks.

Comment: Report a bug on firefox: http://bugs.mozilla.org

Comment: reported as suggested: bun number 773266

Comment: Also reported to d3: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/704

Comment: D3 bug closed as browser issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works in Chrome and Safari and is broken in Firefox 14 (and maybe earlier).
It is fixed in Firefox 15 and onwards.
See bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773266

I have tested it on Firefox 14 (it fails) and 15 (it passes).

The answer to the original question is:
Because it is broken in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It also happened to me. But I solved it by the following way. Open firebug. goto svg > defs > marker section. Then make changes to refX and refY value. It works for me.

Comment: Do you mean the following? <defs>
<marker id="suit" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="15" refY="-1.5" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
<marker id="licensing" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="15" refY="-1.5" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
<marker id="resolved" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="15" refY="-1.5" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">  Change them to what? Can't you do it programmatically?

Comment: ya. try to change refX and/or refY value and you will immediately notice the arrow-markers move.

Comment: do you mean I have to go by trial error? Or there is a fixed adjustment for firefox that can be programmatically added when detecting the browser in the code?

Answer (score 0):

may have been a cut and paste error? it works fine here. http://jsbin.com/akulid/edit#html,live

Comment: Thanks Damen. The only difference is that I only include the new d3.v2.js instead of   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?1.29.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.geom.js?1.29.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.layout.js?1.29.1"></script>. Are these files included in the new d3.v2.js? I tried to add them but firefox tells me that they cannot be found. Could you please suggest changes to make the arrows straight? Thanks

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior (arrows in the wrong direction on FF but not Webkit based browsers like Chrome or Safari) with both the 1.29 and v2 versions of D3.js